# Sort to have non-consecutive column values

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm, sorting, columnsorting

is this possible in mysql queries? Current data table is:

```
id - fruit - name
1 - Apple - George
2 - Banana - George
3 - Orange - Jake
4 - Berries - Angela
```

In the `name` column, i would like to sort it so there is no consecutive name on my `select` query.

My desires output would be, no consecutive `george` in  name column.

```
id - fruit - name
1 - Apple - George
3 - Orange - Jake
2 - Banana - George
4 - Berries - Angela
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have two separate queries, do alternate fetch.

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ?

Comment: That's difficult. And it's rather the opposite of one would call sorting :-) What if you have Angela-George-George-George? There is no way to sort these four so to have all George separate. What is the query to do in such situation? Crash?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya 5.5.56-MariaDB Server

Comment: You have tagged your request "sql". But you are not looking for an answer on SQL (e.g. how to fix your SQL query or how to apply your algorithm in SQL - you have neither a query nor even an algorithm). You are looking for an algorithm instead. So you should remove the database-related tags and replace them with an "algorithm" tag.

Comment: I've added the "algorithm" tag. I've also finally come up with an answer showing a suitable algorithm and even a standard SQL query applying that algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL 8+, you can do:

```
order by row_number() over (partition by name order by id)
```

In earlier versions, you can do this using variables.

Answer (score 1):

Following solution would work for [all the MySQL versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52948761/sort-to-have-non-consecutive-column-values/52949055#comment92807393_52948761), especially **version < 8.0**

- In a [Derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), first sort your actual table, using `name` and `id`.
- Then, determine the row number for a particular row, within all the rows having same `name` value.
- Now, use this result-set and sort it by the **row number** values. So, all the rows having *row number = 1* will come first (for all the different `name` value(s)) and so on. Hence, consecutive `name` rows wont appear.

You can try the following using [User-defined Session Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html):

```
SELECT dt2.id,
       dt2.fruit,
       dt2.name
FROM   (SELECT @row_no := IF(@name_var = dt1.name, @row_no + 1, 1) AS row_num,
               dt1.id,
               dt1.fruit,
               @name_var := dt1.name                               AS name
        FROM   (SELECT id,
                       fruit,
                       name
                FROM   your_table_name
                ORDER  BY name,
                          id) AS dt1
               CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_no := 0,
                                  @name_var := '') AS user_init_vars) AS dt2
ORDER  BY dt2.row_num,
          dt2.id
```

### [DB Fiddle DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b4DMTCR4KAiepoidHDptdL/0)

Comment: Hi, im testing this approach but when I test to add another george row, it still display as consecutive https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8amYX6iRu8AsnYXJYz15DF/0

Comment: @bumbumpaw It is what Thorsten [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52948761/sort-to-have-non-consecutive-column-values/52949055?noredirect=1#comment92806976_52948761) . Sorting will not work if you have more rows of same name than others. Very difficult to achieve in that case.

Comment: Hmm, ok ok I get it. I need to manipulate it with using php then so to save result it to another array. something like that.

Comment: @bumbumpaw Even PHP wont be able to help. Let's say you have total 10 rows and 6 rows for George in that. How would you fit in all George name(s), so that they are not consecutive

Comment: @bumbumpaw: Your altered fiddle shows why this is so difficult. The only solution to sort three Georges, one Jake and one Angela would be to make Jake and Angela rows #2 and #4. However, from a mere database point of view, Jake is like Angela; they both have one single row in the table, so what rule to apply to make one row #2 and one row #4? What you really need is an algorithm for the task. And then it may be easier to apply that algorithm with a programming language, rather than SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'George'),
(2,'George'),
(3,'Jake'),
(4,'Angela');

SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.name = x.name 
   AND y.id <= x.id
 GROUP 
    BY x.id
 ORDER
    BY COUNT(*)
     , id;

+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | George |
|  3 | Jake   |
|  4 | Angela |
|  2 | George |
+----+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my algorithm:

1. count each name's frequency
2. order by frequency descending and name
3. cut into partitions as large as the maximum frequency
4. number rows within each partition
5. order by row number and partition number

An example: Names A, B, C, D, E

```
 step 1 and 2
 ------------
 AAAAABBCCDDEE

 step 3 and 4
 ------------
 12345     
 AAAAA
 BBCCD
 DEE

 step 5
 ------
 ABDABEACEACAD
```

The query:

```
with counted as
(
  select id, fruit, name, count(*) over (partition by name) as cnt
  from mytable 
)
select id, fruit, name
from counted
order by
  (row_number() over (order by cnt desc, name) - 1) % max(cnt) over (),
  row_number() over (order by cnt desc, name);
```

Common table expression (`WITH` clauses) and window functions (aggregation `OVER`) are available as of MySQL 8 or MariaDB 10.2. Before that you can retreat to subqueries, which will make the same query quite long and hard to read, though. I suppose you could also use variables instead, somehow.

DB fiddle demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8amYX6iRu8AsnYXJYz15DF/1