# Only show latest message from each conversation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a messaging system which has the tables "message" which just contains the "subject" then "message_user" which contains the message body, who sent it, who its for and whether its deleted / unread.

```
#Message Table

CREATE TABLE `message` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subject` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `message` (`id`, `subject`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Test'),
    (2, 'Test Again');

#Message User Table

CREATE TABLE `message_user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `message_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `interlocutor` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `body` text,
  `folder` enum('inbox','sent') NOT NULL,
  `starmark` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `unread` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `deleted` enum('none','trash','deleted') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'none',
  `date` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `message_user` (`id`, `message_id`, `user_id`, `interlocutor`, `body`, `folder`, `starmark`, `unread`, `deleted`, `date`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, 2, 'Hi, how are you?', 'sent', 0, 1, 'none', '2018-10-23 09:36:02'),
    (2, 1, 2, 1, 'Hi, how are you?', 'inbox', 0, 1, 'none', '2018-10-23 09:36:02'),
    (3, 1, 2, 1, 'I am good thanks, you?', 'sent', 0, 1, 'none', '2018-10-23 09:46:02'),
    (4, 1, 1, 2, 'I am good thanks, you?', 'inbox', 0, 1, 'none', '2018-10-23 09:46:02'),
    (5, 2, 1, 3, 'Hi!', 'sent', 0, 1, 'none', '2018-10-23 09:50:22'),
    (6, 2, 3, 1, 'Hi!', 'inbox', 0, 1, 'none', '2018-10-23 09:50:22');
```

I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM message m
JOIN message_user mu ON m.id = mu.message_id
WHERE mu.deleted = 'none'
    AND mu.user_id = 1 #user_id of person checking messages
ORDER BY mu.id DESC;
```

But this is currently returning 3 rows even though there is only two conversations. I tried to GROUP BY but it still showed 3 rows.

[image]

I would expect the first two rows in the above example not the last one.

I want the query to return a list of the conversations with the latest message which has been sent which I (user_id) am involved in.

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ?

Comment: Use ranking function (http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-rank-function/), or check this post if your version is too old : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/rank-function-in-mysql

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya MySQL version 8.0.12

Comment: Try adding `group by m.id`

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I get the error of "Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'hidden.mu.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by" - I tried adding that column in GROUP BY too and the query runs but doesn't return only 1 row for each message.

Comment: Please edit your question to add relevant sample data showcasing your case. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Added sample data.

Comment: @ElliotReeve problem is that for a same message id , you have two rows having different folder value. Which one do you want to keep ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya - If my user_id = user_id then I want to keep "sent" as that means I was the last to reply. If user_id != user_id then "inbox" as it means the latest message is received.

But folder is irrelevant as there should only be one message per "user_id" which is in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Since [your MySQL version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52949860/only-show-latest-message-from-each-conversation/52950969#comment92807801_52949860) is 8.0+, we can utilize [Window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html), such as [`Row_number()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number); otherwise the solution would have been much verbose, [using Session variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52949055/2469308).
- For a partition (group) of `m.id`, we will determine the row number values. Row number values will be ordered in descending order of `date`.
- Now, we simply need to use this result-set as a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), and just consider those rows where row number value is 1.
- `Date` is a [keyword in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-D). You should avoid naming column/table using it. Still if you have to do so, you will need to use backticks around it.

Try the following (**[DB Fiddle DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gyR12ZFe6yMZm2nHfaaVNJ/1)**):

```
SELECT  dt.*
FROM (
      SELECT  m.id,
              m.subject,
              mu.id AS message_user_id,
              mu.message_id,
              mu.user_id,
              mu.interlocutor,
              mu.body,
              mu.folder,
              mu.starmark,
              mu.unread,
              mu.deleted,
              mu.`date`,
              Row_number()
                OVER (PARTITION BY m.id 
                      ORDER BY mu.`date` DESC) AS row_no
        FROM  message m
        JOIN  message_user mu
          ON  m.id = mu.message_id
        WHERE mu.deleted = 'none'
          AND mu.user_id = 1 ) AS dt
WHERE    dt.row_no = 1
ORDER BY dt.id DESC
```

Comment: This is close but when I reply to a message it doesn't show that as the lastest body. If you look at the data, for message id 1 the body should show 'I am good thanks, you?' but it doesn't?

Comment: @ElliotReeve should the latest row only appear for a message_id. Because your earlier comment suggested that `sent` should come before `inbox` values.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. I also updated date to created_date :)

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but how would I show all inbox messages that are for user_id (no sent). With an column to show whether I have "replied" or not? Thanks

Comment: @ElliotReeve Look at `Case .. When()` expressions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182376/discussion-between-elliot-reeve-and-madhur-bhaiya).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
select 
    m.id as id_message, m.subject as subject_message,
    mu.id as id_message_user, mu.interlocutor, mu.body, mu.folder, mu.starmark, mu.deleted, mu.date 
from message as m
inner join message_user as mu on mu.message_id = m.id and mu.deleted = 'none' and mu.user_id = 1
group by id_message
order by id_message_user desc
```

I removed

- **mu.user_id** : it's in the inner join condition so always 'none'
- **mu.unread** :same, always 1
- **mu.message_id** : duplicate of id_message

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91a5e4/15

Comment: Thanks but I get an error:
"Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'hidden.mu.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

Comment: You get this error with a copy/paste of this query? I added a Fiddle and I have no error with this :s

Comment: Look strange for me since I had the same error and I corrected it in the fiddle using alias. About your error I find this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql